# Package recursive classes access

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating a library (jar) based on spring of following structure:

- com.mycompany.mylib/

  - **external-api**/
  - internal-objects/
  - internal-classes/

classes in *external-api* use classes in *internal-** packages.

How can make only *external-api* package visible for the client?

Comment: Package level modularity is not supported by normal JAR files. All you can do is make classes in `.internal....*` packages package private and in `external...*` public. However even then someone can declare a package with your internal package name and access classes inside it. If you want true modularity you can use OSGI bundles.

Comment: If I make internal-* classes package private I cant't access them from external-api package...

Comment: If your requirement can be fulfilled by making internal packages package private then you can create a utility class in external package and load classes from internal package using reflection.

Comment: Also if you're willing to use reflection then you can keep `internal package` inside a `secret` folder that way it won't be accessible on classpath. When you need the classes in there, in external package you can load classes from it at runtime using ClassLoader.defineClass().

Comment: You mean to use some public factories in internal-* packages to load package private classes from external-* packages and, maybe, have some logic inside the factories to disallow access from outside of com.mycompany.mylib... 
This will answer my needs, but i'm concerned about some overhead here. I hoped there is more elegant solution to do it.

Comment: Yes exactly, only elegant solution is OSGI bundle but that would require you and users of the API to move to OSGI container.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984854/enforcing-layered-architecture-in-java

Comment: @AdamSkywalker that post covers only compile time exclusion, only Jörg's answer (OSGI) covers runtime segregation.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I think OSGi is good and complicated  design approach and Maven exclusion looks like kind of trick but simple to implement.